# Getting Flask object has no attribute 'appbuilder' on flask fab create-user

Tags: python, flask, flask-appbuilder

I was trying to create a new user from the terminal using flask fab but when I run the command and fill all the required info like `username`, `email`, `password` I get this error message: `AttributeError: 'Flask' object has no attribute 'appbuilder'`.

Full traceback:

https://pastebin.com/gACSfChG

```
FLASK_APP=run.py
```

**run.py**

```
import os

from app import RubyAPP

config_name = os.getenv('FLASK_CONFIG')
app = RubyAPP(config_name).app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager
from flask_login import current_user
from flask import render_template

db = SQLAlchemy()
app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found_404(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404

class RubyAPP(object):

    def __init__(self, config_name):
        # App manager
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
        db.init_app(app)

        # Login manager
        login_manager.init_app(app)
        login_manager.login_message = 'You must be logged in to access this page'
        login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'

        # Flask migrate
        migrate = Migrate(app, db)

    def app(self):
        # Error handling apps registers
        app.register_error_handler(404, not_found_404)

        # Models
        from app import models

        # Views
        from .home import home as home_blueprint
        app.register_blueprint(home_blueprint)

        from .profile.links import links as links_blueprint
        app.register_blueprint(links_blueprint)

        from .login import login as login_blueprint
        app.register_blueprint(login_blueprint)

        return app
```

I tried reinstalling `appbuilder` but gives the same error. I think these 2 files are enough but since I don't know whats giving the error let me know if you need any extra file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same error. You have to run `appbuilder.init_app()` for your app:

```
..
..
class RubyAPP(object):
    def __init__(self, config_name):
        # App manager
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
        db.init_app(app)

        with app.app_context():
            appbuilder.init_app(app, db.session)
..
..
```